# Android AsyncTask cancel with message

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that shows a dialog when runing. When i click cancel :

```
 if (isCancelled()) break;
```

How to display a message in a dialog ( with "ok" button ) when i cancel the asyncTask?

Thanks

Comment: Create a runOnUiThreadBlock inside that if statement.  Inside the block, display a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask has a method just for that

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    // Show the dialog
}
```

`onCancelled` is only called if cancel is called. However note the docs: **Runs on the UI thread** after `cancel(boolean)` is invoked and `doInBackground(Object[])` has finished.

This means onCancelled will not be called immediately on any thread.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create an alert dialog and display it in the onCancelled method of AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
              dialog.show();
         }
     });
}
```

To know on creation of dialog, you can follow this: [Alert dialog with a button](https://androiddesk.wordpress.com/tag/alert-dialog-with-one-button/)